# Storing user settings in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface

First of all should I use a file or database? or something else that is better?

How should I design the tables in my MySQL database to allow different users to login with their preferences. Often I have seen many sites that allow the the user to customize what is visible to him within the website.

Are the options settings saved in the database or its not persistent? what would be the best way to do this?

If I do need a database as a solution, how many tables will be required?

Comment: If you have a user/password table already, the easiest would be to just add a column "preferences" where you store the settings. To store preferences persistent or not is your choice.

Comment: Most likely it would be one table, something along the lines of `(userID, option1, option2, option3, option4, ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used a bitmask of options for this. It doesn't lock you into a fixed set of 'options' as you can always add new values to the mask. You don't have to worry about keeping table definitions in synch with new user options as the site changes.